# How can i mount volume of glusterfs to /var/lib/docker in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, glusterfs

I installed gluster-server and docker on ubuntu 14.04

```
# install Glusterfs
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties;
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:gluster/glusterfs-3.6;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install -y glusterfs-server;

gluster peer probe $NODE1_DNS;
gluster volume create file_store_docker replica 2 transport tcp $NODE1_DNS:/brickdocker $PUBLIC_DNS:/brickdocker force;
gluster volume start file_store_docker;
sudo mkdir /var/lib/docker;
mount -t glusterfs $PUBLIC_DNS:/file_store_docker /var/lib/docker;

# install Docker with AUFS
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r);
sudo sh -c "wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/gpg | apt-key add -";
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main\ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list";
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get -y install lxc-docker;
```

When i run below line

> sudo docker run -p 80:80 --name docker-wordpress-nginx -d
>   eugeneware/docker-wordpress-nginx

And i got this message:

> Error response from daemon: error creating aufs mount to
>   /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0b78a98c13f26eebcdef6517654ff80bdf6b35f433ac06be632aa55e8f3bb4a1-init:
>   file too large

Can you help me to understand this error? How do i mount volume of glusterfs to /var/lib/docker in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I guess the file created by your command `gluster volume create file_store_docker replica 2 xxxxx` is bigger than the limit in docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error and with some luck i found:
[Can several nodes access mounted docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275572/can-several-nodes-access-mounted-docker-containers)

So I stopped docker:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

added in the /etc/default/docker:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-s devicemapper"

sudo service docker start
```

This works for me, hopefully for you too.

Comment: it worked for me too. Thank you very much. I have one question :). After starting docker on server, I browsed my web site with ip address x.x.x.123. On server 2 (ip: x.x.x.49), it had the same files and directories in /var/lib/docker. But I couldn't browse my website with x.x.x.49. I checked container of docker in server 2 by "docker ps", I didn't see any containers. Can you help me? How do I share docker between servers by glusterfs